# Are these algebraic expressions equivalent in 'form'?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

This sounds silly, but I am wondering if the algebraic expressions $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ and $2^n(2^{n+1}-1)$ are equivalent in form (assuming $n \in \mathbb{N}$) ?

When I say form, I mean it in the context that it was used in a proof, in which "we have $p = 2^kq$ and we must show it has 'form' $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$."

I think the answer to my question is yes, but I am unsure of what *exactly* form is.

I think in the two algebraic expressions I gave, they are equivalent in form because the actual value of $n$ is not relevant to the the mathematical object $p$, it only matters that $p$ is defined in such a way that it captures its form: that the first power in the expressions is one less than the second power. So I could also say that $2^{n-1000}(2^{n-999}-1)$ has equivalent form.

My thinking here is that $n$ is simply a dummy variable, and what matters more is the relationship between the objects $n$ and $n-1$. Is this correct?

Also I think the reason they are equivalent in form is that if we think about the sets these expressions produce over all the natural numbers, $$\{p : p =  2^{n-1}(2^n-1)\wedge n \in \mathbb{N}\}  = \{p : p =  2^{n-1000}(2^{n-999}-1)\wedge n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Is this a sound argument?

Apologies again if this is an inappropriate question.

Comment: *"I think [...] it only matters that $p$ is defined in such a way that it captures its form: that the first power in the expression is one less than the second power."* ... You think correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct. However, the expression $2^n(2^{n+1}-1)$ is preferable in this context, because it defines a positive integer for every $n\in \Bbb N$. The value of the other expression $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ is $0$ for $n = 0$, but notice that $n-1$ is no longer a natural number when $n=0$. The expression $2^{n-2}(2^{n-1}-1)$ would be even worse, forcing you to consider rational numbers to get its value for $n = 0$. Thus, formally, your last equality should be stated as follows:
$$
\{ p \in \Bbb{N} \mid \text{there exists $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $p = 2^n(2^{n+1}-1)$} \} = \{ p \in \Bbb{N} \mid \text{there exists $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $p = 2^{n-1000}(2^{n-999}-1)$} \}
$$
This may look like picky details, but there are highly relevant for programming languages: in C, if you declare $n$ to be an unsigned integer, you may have problems to compute $n-1000$...

Comment: (With a note that $\Bbb N$ is not always defined as containing $0$...)